# Store tweets into Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, twitter

Have a requirement to track certain URLs on Twitter.

1)Is it possible to specify partial URL pattern in Twitter Track parameter? e.g. if I want to search for all the URLs containing http://abc.co/ which will include http://abc.co/122, http://abc.co/456 etc. Is this possible with Twitter Stream API?

2)What's the efficient way to store all the tweets into MongoDB? Tweets will be used for analytical purposes.

I am using Scala 2.10 and MongoDB

Update: Alright, after digging in understanding some Iteratee concepts, I have put together a quick test as follow

```
WS.url("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=" + term)
  .sign(OAuthCalculator(Twitter.KEY, tokens))
  .get(_ => printingIteratee)


 def printingIteratee = Iteratee.foreach[Array[Byte]] { chunk =>
   val json = Json.parse(new String(chunk))
   val user = (json \ "user" \ "screen_name").as[String]
   val content = (json \ "text").as[String]

   println("user " + user)
   println("content " + content)

 }
```

Above Iteratee is for a test which is for side-effect and doesn't return anything.

I am trying to come up with an Iteratee which takes Array[Byte] and creates an object to store in MongoDB. Had a quick look at Iteratee.fold and few methods but still not quite sure how to create an Iteratee that takes Array[Byte] and produces an object (say case class Tweet) that can be stored to MongoDB. Any pointers in creating such Iteratee will be appreciated.

Comment: As far as #2 is concerned you should write the code and then to optimize it you could post it at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: #2 is also very similar to your other question [Collect real time tweets continuously, store into local datastore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280565/collect-real-time-tweets-continuously-store-into-local-datastore)

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#track) states:

> URLs are considered words for the purposes of matches which means that the entire domain and path must be included in the track query for a Tweet containing an URL to match.

It also contains a table where they say:

`example.com` will match `Someday I will visit example.com` but will not match `There is no example.com/foobarbaz`

As far as I can tell it's not possible to track a domain with all of it's sub domains.

Comment: Thanks EECOLOR. I am learning some how Futures,Promise etc work in Scala and here I am trying to seek guidance from others on design part first before writing any code. To collect real time Tweets and store into MongoDB in real time as well, how would you design in Scala? Again, I am quite new to Futures, Promise,Streams etc. It'll be helpful to have some guidance.

Comment: The documentation on [futures and promises](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) might help. [This project](https://github.com/Rhinofly/GitHubRawFileProxy/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.scala) file contains an example. If you are new to something do not try to design up front. Just hack something together to get a feel and understanding. Then throw your code away and design with the knowledge you gained. If you run into specific problems post them here, StackOverflow is the perfect place to answer concrete questions.